# Upper bound for dependent variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, upper-lower-bounds

If i have a set of $n$ dependent variables $\{n_1,...n_n\}$

The probability of success for every one of those variables is equal to $k$ but if there is one variable that succeeded the probability that another variable will succeed is $k'<k$.

Is there any problem if i assume that the variables are indenpendent and follow a binomial distribution to derive an upper bound on the probability of $x$ variables succeed?

Comment: This should be possible. Basically you have a stochastic domination of your sequence by some binomial random variable. Depending on what you want to compute, you will either look at a binomial with parameter $k$ or $k'$ (assuming that after two successes your $k'$ you don't have a new even smaller $k''$).

Comment: Actually thats exactly the case. The probability of success for one variable is $k$ but if one variable already succeeds the probability for another variable succeed is $k' < k$. If two variable succeed the probability of another variable succeed is $k''  < k' $. 
But since the probability is decreasing as the number of occurences is increasing isn't it still possible to assume that?

Comment: Yes you will still be able to conclude. Do you need something very rigorous or not ? I can write you the basic steps I think.

Comment: Any help would be amazing! It does not need to be an article demonstration but i could use some sort of guidance. Thank you already for your insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the idea is (roughly) to use stochastic domination.
Consider the sequence $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ of random variables that you are considering. Consider also a sequence $(Y_1,\dots,Y_n)$ of random variables of parameter $(m,k)$ ($m$ tries, $k$ probability of success for each try). You have
$$ \mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \ge x) \le \mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i \ge x) = \mathbb{P}(Z_n \ge x), $$
where $Z_n = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$.

The last quantity in the RHS can be computed explicitely: $Z_n$ is a binomial r.v. of parameter (mn, k). Now my inequality above is not fully obvious, see below if you need the details.

Bonus track : to justify this with a coupling, let $U$ be a uniform random variable on $(0,1)$ and $k' < k$. Consider
$$ X = \mathbf{1}_{U \le k'}, \qquad Y = \mathbf{1}_{U \le k}. $$
With this construction, $X \sim \mathcal{B}(k')$, $Y \sim \mathcal{B}(k)$ and $X \le Y$ for all $\omega$ in your probability space (i.e. for all realization of $U$). Now you can build

- First of whole sequence $A^1, \dots, A^m$ and $C^1,\dots, C^m$ that you sum to get your binomial $X_1 \sim \mathcal{Bin}(m,k')$ and $Y_1 \sim \mathcal{Bin}(m,k)$. As $A^i \le C^i$ for all $i$, $X_1 \le Y_1$.
- Once this is clear, you get your whole sequence of $(X_i)_{i \ge 1}$ and $(Y_i)_{i \ge 1}$ using this and obtain exactly the sequence $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ and $(Y_1,\dots,Y_n)$ desired, with $X_j \le Y_j$ for all $j \ge 1$, which fully justifies my computation.

Comment: Just a question to make sure i dont make any wrong assumptions. When you type $\mathcal{Bin}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ you are referring both times to the binomial distribution?

Comment: No sorry, I've read your problem too fast. $\mathcal{B}$ is Bernoulli, $\mathcal{Bin}$ is binomial. A binomial $(m,k)$ is the sum of $m$ indepent Bernoulli random variables of parameter $k$. I've edited my answer accordingly.